# Перекидывать ссылки с одного потока в другой JAVA

Tags: java, многопоточность, concurrency, task

У меня есть картинки которые нужно загрузить я хочу сделать так что есть один поток который загружает картинки и есть второй который передает туда(в первый) ссылки для загрузки. Подскажите, пожалуйста) Можно не на картинка, просто какой нибудь шаблон)

Comment: а Вы можете предоставить имеющийся код, чтобы отвечающие могли брать в расчёт Вашу конкретную реализацию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идея следующая, у вас есть очередь с блокировкой, т.е. в неё можно положить, а прочитать только тогда, когда там что-то есть, иначе она просто ожидает.

Таким образом будет что-то такое:

```
private BlockingQueue<String> s = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(5);

public User initThread() {
  try {
    s.put("URL");
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  Thread t = new Thread(()->{
    try {
      processing(s.take());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  });
}
```

Т.е. когда другие потоки будут класть в очередь `s` строку, поток `t`, будет его обрабатывать.